# Grub recovery throwing error

Tags: grub2, 20.04

warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklistsHowever, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged...

grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists.

Why Blocklists are unreliable. and how to use these blocklists.

Comment: Why would you want block lists? And where are you installing grub that it needs to use blocklists? There almost always are better ways. Post this and where you are installing grub. `sudo parted -l` Block lists are hard coded addresses to find rest of grub in your install from the boot files. Even a fsck can move a file and that breaks grub. Where you are attempting to install grub is too small for grub2.  Usually an issue with installing grub to a partition, which you never should do or installing to MBR of gpt drive without bios_grub partition.But now most systems are UEFI.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing my grub recovery in legacy mode when I changed mode to UEFI mode. I made a bootable device in the MBR Partition scheme and FAT(32) file system mode by using Rufus and I recovered normally by using live Ubuntu boot manager . After recovery, I again switch UEFI mode to legacy mode and everything worked fine.